# Regex to match alphanumerics, URL operators except forward slashes

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I've been trying for the past couple of hours to get this regex right but unfortunately, I still can't get it. Tried searching through existing threads too but no dice. :(

I'd like a regex to match the following possible strings:

```
userprofile?id=123
profile
search?type=player&gender=male
someotherpage.htm
```

but not

```
userprofile/
helloworld/123
```

Basically, I'd like the regex to match **alphanumerics**, **URL operators** such as **?, = and &** but **not forward slashes**. (i.e. As long as the string contains a forward slash, the regex should just return 0 matches.)

I've tried the following regexes but none seem to work:

```
([0-9a-z?=.]+)
(^[^\/]*$[0-9a-z?=.]+)
([0-9a-z?=.][^\/]+)
([0-9a-z?=.][\/$]+)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: So, you just don't want to match a forward slash in your string, and everything else should match? Is it like this? Or it's like, a forward slash after - `"userprofile"` should not be matched?

Comment: What is the language? And I suggest that you preprocess the URL with URI/URL class to split the URL up before validating it.

Comment: Hey @RohitJain, thanks for replying! I just edited my question for clarity.

As long as the string contains a forward slash, the regex should return 0 matches. But it may contain alphanumerics and URL operators such as ?, = and &. (:

Comment: @nhahtdh This regex is for an XML document (URL Rewrite for Struts 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason they all match is that your regexp matches part of the string and you've not told it that it needs to match the entire string. You need to make sure that it doesn't allow any other characters anywhere in the string, e.g.

```
^[0-9a-z&?=.]+$
```

Here's a small perl script to test it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @testlines = (
         "userprofile?id=123",
         "userprofile",
         "userprofile?type=player&gender=male",
         "userprofile.htm",
         "userprofile/",
         "userprofile/123",
        );

foreach my $testline(@testlines) {
  if ($testline =~ /^[0-9a-z&?=.]+$/) {
    print "$testline matches\n";
  } else {
    print "$testline doesn't match - bad regexp, no cookie\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Thanks a million!

Because this is for an XML document, I modified slightly to escape the ampersand like so: ^[0-9a-z&amp;?=.]+$

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
/\w+(\.htm|\?\w+=\w*(&\w+=\w*)*)?$/i
```

To break this down:

```
\w+              // Match [a-z0-9_] (1 or more), to specify resource
  (              // Alternation group (i.e., a OR b)
    \.htm        // Match ".htm"
    |            // OR
    \?           // Match "?"
    \w+=\w*      // Match first term of query string (e.g., something=foo)
    (&\w+=\w*)*  // Match remaining terms of query string (zero or more)
  )
?                // Make alternation group optional
$                // Anchor to end of string
```

The `i` flag is for case-insensitivity.

Comment: Sorry @Xophmeister, I wasn't too clear in my question. Just edited it further for clarity.

The preceding string needn't always be 'userprofile'. The regex should return a match for alphanumerics and URL operators (such as ?, = and &). But as long as the string contains a forward slash, it should return no matches!

Thanks for your help!